# Work function and surface and lattice binding energy

Tags: solid-state-physics, metals

How work function and surface and lattice binding energy are related in a metal?

I need to estimate with [SRIM](http://srim.org/) the changes of the work function of a gold slab after bombardment of ions, but SRIM reports the surface and lattice binding energy (see [this site](http://www.srim.org/SRIM/Tutorials/SRIM%20Tutorial%204%20-%20Target%20Damage.pdf)): how can I deduce the work function?

Comment: In 35 years of using SRIM, I've never used it for that before. GIven what I know under-the-hood of SRIM, I'm not sure that I'd believe that answer all that much anyways, compared to something more intimately connected to electronic structure (be it DFT or something else).